# In XML file, i have this symbol "&amp" in an element in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing

In XML File, i have this symbol in middle of element like below showing code.

```
<title>CHAIRMAN BOB LIEBER INTERVIEWED BY CITY &amp; STATE</title>
```

once i read this content, i will get STATE only. So how to solve this issue to get like this, CHAIRMAN BOB LIEBER INTERVIEWED BY CITY & STATE

Comment: How are you reading it? Is it plain XML or a plist?

Comment: Can u add any parsing code?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in my application

> NSString* contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL
>   URLWithString:LINK_EVENTS_XML]
>                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
>                                                        error:nil];
>
> ```
> // You can pre-process(replace certain characters, ...) content of xml in here.
>
> NSData* xml = [contents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
> ```
>
> NSXMLParser *nsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
>
> ```
> // create and init our delegate
> XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
>
> // set delegate
> [nsXmlParser setDelegate:parser];
>
> // parsing...
> BOOL success = [nsXmlParser parse]; if (success)
> {
>     NSLog(@"No errors - event count : %i", [parser.events count]);
>     // get array of users here
>     //  NSMutableArray *users = [parser users];
>
>     self.eventsArray= parser.events;
>     [self.tblEvents reloadData];
> }
> else
> {
>     NSLog(@"Error parsing document!");
> }
> ```

I figured it had something to do with encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I Found answer by myself just append the strings.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (!currentStringValue)
    {
        currentStringValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    else
    {
    [currentStringValue appendString: [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

    }

}
```